# Arris port forwarding

Tags: windows-10, router, multiplayer, internet-connection, wifi

I am trying to open a port for my unity multiplayer game. I have a arris router, google wifi, and a windows 10 deveice. When setting up port forwarding on the arris setting page, it gives me an error “invalid IP address” How would I forward a port from the arris, to google wifi, to my windows 10 deveice, then finally to the internet so I can set up multiplayer across different networks. Anyone who can help even a little bit is greatly thanked. Also, would there be a faster way to open a port with the set up I have? Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be outside the scope of Stack Overflow as defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @esqew then where should i ask it